# extending static methods in php

Tags: php, static

```
class Foo {
  public static function foobar() {
    self::whereami();
  }

  protected static function whereami() {
    echo 'foo';
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  protected static function whereami() {
    echo 'bar';
  } 
}

Foo::foobar();
Bar::foobar();
```

expected result `foobar` actual result `foofoo`

to make matters worse, the server is restricted to php 5.2

Comment: PHP 5.3 introduced [late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php). Looks like you might be out of luck with 5.2

Answer (score 9):

All you need is a **one-word change!**

The problem is in the way you call *whereami()*, instead of *self::* you should use *static::*. So class *Foo* should look like this:

```
class Foo {
  public static function foobar() {
    static::whereami();
  }
  protected static function whereami() {
    echo 'foo';
  }
}
```

In another word, 'static' actually makes the call to *whereami()* dynamic :) - it depends on what class the call is in.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use singleton pattern:

```
<?php

class Foo {
    private static $_Instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}

    private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_Instance == null) {
            self::$_Instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_Instance;
    }

    public function foobar() {
        $this->whereami();
    }

    protected function whereami() {
        print_r('foo');
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    private static $_Instance = null;

    private function __construct() {}

    private function __clone() {}

    public static function getInstance() {
        if(self::$_Instance == null) {
            self::$_Instance = new self();
        }
        return self::$_Instance;
    }

    protected function whereami() {
        echo 'bar';
    } 
}

Foo::getInstance()->foobar();
Bar::getInstance()->foobar();


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to overwrite the parent function foobar() too?

```
class Foo {
  public static function foobar() {
    self::whereami();
  }
  protected static function whereami() {
    echo 'foo';
  }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
  public static function foobar() {
    self::whereami();
  }
  protected static function whereami() {
    echo 'bar';
  } 
}

Foo::foobar();
Bar::foobar();
```